# Blazor dependency injection error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, orm, blazor

Using SqlSugar ORM, based on blazor, dependency injection business service, an error is reported when calling。
SqlSugarService：

```
 public static class SqlSugarService
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SqlSugarService));
        public static void AddSqlSugarSevice(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            if (services == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        
            services.AddScoped<ISqlSugarClient>(o =>
            {
            
                var listConfig = new List<ConnectionConfig>();
                listConfig.Add(new ConnectionConfig
                {
                    DbType = DbType.SqlServer,
                    ConnectionString = "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;DataBase=Test;Uid=sa;Pwd=123456",
                    IsAutoCloseConnection = true,
                    InitKeyType = InitKeyType.Attribute
                });
                var dbContext = new SqlSugarClient(listConfig);
                
                return dbContext;
               
            });

        }

    }
```

the interface：

```
  public interface IReportRepository
    {
          public DataTable GetTest(string sql);
    }
```

Interface implementation：

```
 public class ReportRepository : IReportRepository
    {
        private ISqlSugarClient _dbBase;
        public ReportRepository(ISqlSugarClient sqlSugar)
        {
             _dbBase = sqlSugar;
         }
    
        
        public DataTable GetTest(string sql)
        {
          return _dbBase.Ado.GetDataTable(sql);
        }

}
```

injection：

```
  services.AddSqlSugarSevice();
  services.TryAddTransient<IReportRepository, ReportRepository>();
```

use constructor injection：

```
   private readonly IReportRepository _reportRepository;

        //[Inject]
        //public IReportRepository ReportService { get; set; }

        public Report(IReportRepository  reportRepository)
        {
            _reportRepository = reportRepository;
            _reportRepository.GetTest("select * from test");
        }
```

**ERROR :**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'MyReport.Pages.Report'.
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(bool publicOnly, bool wrapExceptions, bool fillCache)

[image]

> ```
> public partial class Report
> {
>     private readonly IReportRepository _reportRepository;
>
>     //[Inject]
>     //public IReportRepository ReportService { get; set; }
>     public Report()
>     {
>         
>     }
>     public Report(IReportRepository  reportRepository)
>     {
>         _reportRepository = reportRepository;
>         _reportRepository.GetTest("select * from test");
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

[image]

Comment: _"No parameterless constructor defined for type __'MyReport.Pages.Report'__. "_ - show us that class.

Comment: After adding a parameterless constructor, no error is reported, but I don’t know why, the class code has been added

Comment: Is the injection method wrong?I want to inject, just use

Comment: You should remove it againb - you now have `_reportRepository == null`

Comment: Show the relevant parts of the Report.razor and maybe Report.razor.cs. Looks like you use constructor injection on a Page?

Comment: yes,Report.razor has Nothing but routing

Comment: The code behind the blazor component can only be injected through [Inject]?

Comment: MyReport.Pages.Report is the Report.razor.cs

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that. Pages need property injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Razor Page (Component) you have to use Property Injection, not Constructor Injection. And that means that the injected services are not available in the constructor. That's why we have OnInitialized().

I fixed what I could see, remove the commented-out parts:

```
public partial class Report
{
    //private readonly IReportRepository _reportRepository;

    [Inject]
    public IReportRepository ReportService { get; set; }
    
    //public Report()
    //{        
    //}
    //public Report(IReportRepository  reportRepository)
    //{
    //    _reportRepository = reportRepository;
    //    _reportRepository.GetTest("select * from test");
    //}

    protected override void OnItializedAsync()
    {
       // replace with async version if possible
       // and assign to something?
       ReportService.GetTest("select * from test");                 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've now understood

Comment: Now I see why some devs won't use partial classes in Blazor code behinds - probably for this reason!

Comment: I would reconsider that, real code-behind uses partial. Older Blazor did not support that so you may see inheritance as a workaround but that is definitely for other use cases.